# fetch one array in an array swift

Tags: arrays, sql-server, swift

I am extracting data from the MSSQL server. I assign this data to string array. I want to match these strings with the data entered by the user. I want to search the data entered by the user from the data I have taken. So according to the code, I want to query the equality of the newArrayPassword array with eMailPassword, but there is 100 data in the eMailPassword, and 1 in the newArrayPassword. How do I query if there is 1 data among these 100 data?

```
 @IBAction func loginButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: AnyObject) {

      let email = loginEmailInputView.textFieldView.text
      let password = loginPasswordInputView.textFieldView.text
        let md5Data = MD5(password!)
        let newArrayEmail : [String] =  [email!]
        print("newArrayEmail", newArrayEmail)
        let newArrayPassword : [String] =  [md5Data!]
        print("newArrayPassword", newArrayPassword)

            let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                        client.connect("asd", username: "asd", password: "asd", database: "asd") { success in
            client.execute("SELECT form_sifre FROM uasd", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                            for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                                                     for row in table {
                                                       for (_, value) in row {
                                                        if let intVal = value as? String {
                                                        self.eMailPassword.append(String(intVal))                         
                                                if newArrayPassword == self.eMailPassword {
                                                                }
                                                        }}}}

                                        client.disconnect()})}
}
```

Comment: `newArrayEmail .contains(md5Data)`

Comment: Why don't you add a WHERE predicate to the sql query? That's much more efficient than filtering a received huge array.

Comment: How do I do that? How do I search based on the data entered? @vadian

Comment: Please search **mysql where clause** on google. There are zillions of tutorials.

Comment: How do you use the sql command? do I retrieve data from a user's entered data and do the search? @vadian

Comment: You have to change the *execute* string to `"SELECT form_sifre FROM uasd WHERE ..."`